# Generating PDF with LaTeX source using PHP on webhosting

Tags: php, pdf

I am preparing for my students some tests that should be generated by PHP on a webhosting. I have stored latex-source codes in database and I would like to get PDF together using PDFLaTeX. Is there any solution for that? I can not find anything in PHP.

The obvious answer would be to generate the tex-file and then use shel_exec with texlive install on my machine. But since it is on the webhosting where I can not install texlive, I can't do that in general. I would use mPDF or FPDF, but I need mathematical environment.

If it is not with PHP, is there any change to use some JavaScript libraries on frontend to generate PDF for download?

Thank you.

Comment: No, LaTeX requires a full installation. Perhaps the most cost-effective solution would be to rent a server/VM/VPS where you have root and can install whatever you want. However, if you don't need PDF then you can easily render math on web pages with Mathjax.

Comment: Unfortunately I need PDF to be downloaded. Otherwise I would use the Mathjax happily. :)

Comment: Hi Jimmy, this question has nothing to do with Software Engineering. You are not asking a specific question about 'how can I implement this' but for a general solution to your idea :(

Comment: Hello, thanks, I was actually direct to SE, originally I posted it in web developing. :D It's always nice to know that not only I am confused by categories here.